# Extra dimensions and the big bang

Tags: string-theory, big-bang, spacetime-dimensions, compactification, string-theory-landscape

If there were extra compact dimensions,and at the big bang all dimensions were compact,my question is why the big bang failed to expand those presumed extra dimensions like it did with the 3 spatial classical dimensions and time?Moreover the expansion is still ongoing so why the presumed extra dimensions are fixed in size?Does this have anything to do with the initial energy available at the big bang?Would this validate the many world hypothesis so that the number of the expanded dimensions and the still compact ones are random?or would this help to "dismiss" the whole idea of extra dimensions?

Comment: More on dimension of spacetime: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651/2451 and links therein.

Comment: More or less duplicate of & see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73954/

Comment: Are we talking about extra dimensions at the Planck scale, or large extra dimensions in the sense of http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0402168 ? I think the answer is completely different in the two cases: a speculative answer based on quantum-gravity in the former, a non-speculative answer based on classical GR in the latter.